# RegEx yymmdd matching in Bulk Rename Utility

Tags: regex, date, pdf, metadata

I have a file repository with about 750k files that I'm looking to filter using the excellent tool Bulk Rename Utility (BRU) http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk

Two questions, the first - I'm wanting two RegEx expressions that either include or exclude files that match the filename prefix (yymmdd ), where:

1. yy = dates between say 1990 (90) and 2050 (50)
2. mm = 01 to 12
3. dd = 01 to 31
4. followed by a space

AND

1. with the following extensions
2. *.pdf *.doc *.docx *.xls *.xlsx *.ppt *.pptx *.mpp *.mpx *.vsd *.vsdx *.zip *.iso *.txt *.eml

Files should be in the following format 160714 filename.pdf, and not 160714filename.pdf or 1607140000 filename.pdf

So far I've come up with the following (RegEx n00b) include expression, but I can't get the exclude to work, and also multiple extensions are not working - only one at a time, and the digit restrictions to yy/mm/dd are not there

- (^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ) *.pdf *.doc *.docx *.xls *.xlsx *.ppt *.pptx *.mpp *.mpx *.vsd *.vsdx *.zip *.iso *.txt *.eml

So two include and exclude expressions that allow me to run multiple passes and sorting where I can then apply multiple actions to the entire repository.

The second - I can mostly pull the created/modified dates from the file metadata except PDF.  I'm trying to find a (cheap) batch program to update the windows/mac metadata with the PDF created/modified dates on the entire repository. This would allow me to use BRU to update the filenames using the correct metadata, and not with the windows/mac dates the files were copied. There are thousand dollar programs that do it, but these are beyond my budget.

Any suggestions.?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've just been looking a little harder here http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/PDF.html and may have partly answered my second question - use ExifTool to pull the created/modified PDF metadata and write this to the windows/mac properties of each file.

I was previously looking to use ExifTool to do the batching as well, but my preference now is to use http://bulkrenameutility.co.uk for this as it filters and sorts a lot better, however ExifTool looks to be able to do the metadata updates that BRU can't.

So the updated second question is, what is the ExifTool command for this, leaving the renaming now to BRU.?